# Can I edit the OSX application menu for my java swing app?

Tags: java, macos, swing

We have an application we distribute as a runnable jar. It has got a pull-down menu containing About, License and Exit.

To integrate this better I removed this menu when the app is running in OSX and I handle the 'about' menu item from the OSX application menu instead. Quit is also on there and already works as expected.

I already managed to set the title correctly by setting the appropriate System property. I also managed to change the dock icon from a coffee cup to the icon the application would use on Windows/Linux (but with a better resolution)

1: Is it possible for me to add a menu item (in this case license) to the auto-generated OSX application menu?

2: Can I remove items I don't need/like? (in this case I don't know what the 'services' sub-menuitem is doing there - it doesn't seem to do anything)

I have seen several suggestions on how this may be done using JavaFX. I would like to do this using swing.

Comment: Since `com.apple.eawt.Application` only provides handler interaction for things like "About", but provides no direct access to the auto generated menu, I'd suggest "no", there doesn't appear to be a "simple" way to achieve it

Comment: @MadProgrammer For ‘About’ and ‘Preferences,’ there are new methods in [java.awt.Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).  No need to rely on com.apple.\* classes anymore.  But no way to add a custom License menu item, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @VGR So it's just taking over from `com.apple.eawt.Application` ... it's not actually adding a "new" functionality which wasn't available in `*.eawt.*` though :( - Still, at least it will compile across different platforms without requiring the use of reflection

Comment: @MadProgrammer Correct.  I seem to recall seeing a Java team discussion that acknowledged that they were simply making the com.apple.eawt APIs into official cross-platform APIs, in fact.

Comment: Unfortunately, those new methods in java.awt.Desktop are added in version 9 which we don't use.